# Spring cloud stream Kafka consumer stuck with long running job and large value for max.poll.interval.ms

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We have got some long-running jobs that have been also implemented with Spring Cloud Stream and Kafka binder. The issue we are facing is because the default value for `max.poll.interval.ms` and `max.poll.records` is not appropriate for our use case, we need to set a relatively large value for `max.poll.interval.ms` (a few hours) and a relatively small value for `max.poll.records` (e.g. 1) to be aligned with the longest-running job could ever get consumed by the consumer. This addresses the issue of a consumer getting into the rebalance loop. However, it causes some operational challenges with the consumer. It happens sometimes that the consumer gets stuck on the restart and does not consume any messages until the `max.poll.interval.ms` passes.

Is this because of the way that the Spring Cloud stream poll has been implemented? Does it help if I use the sync consumer and manages the `poll()` accordingly?

The consumer logs the lose of heartbeat and the message I can see in the Kafka log when the consumer has stuck:

```
GroupCoordinator 11]: Member consumer-3-f46e14b4-5998-4083-b7ec-bed4e3f374eb in group foo has failed, removing it from the group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring cloud stream (message-driven) is not a good fit for this application. It would be better to manage the consumer yourself; close it after the `poll()`; process the job; create a new consumer and commit the offset, and `poll()` again.

Comment: It's hard to do that as it's one of the consumers of many in the service that requires long-running jobs. Pretty much everything else has been implemented with Spring Cloud Stream and works as expected in this application. Is there any way to change the behaviour of one specific consumer in Spring Cloud Stream? does it help if I use pollable consumer for the long-running job?

Comment: Yes, you could switch to the pollable source but you would need to pause it, and keep polling regularly while the job is running; then resume it to get the next record. If you need help with that I can try to put an example together.

Comment: Yes, an example would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Example [here](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/e2c1ce82c5a5556215b5e4e2eaf0c8d1).

Comment: So to clarify this approach, because you are using 'pause' and 'resume' the consumer would not actually consume messages and ignore them, it acts smartly to fake the poll and just passes the health check bounded to the poll(). Is that right? What would happen if more than a single partition are allocated to the consumer? Would it be able to pause all of them as the pause/resume works per partition?

Comment: That is correct; pausing the consumer allows us to satisfy the requirement to call `poll()` within `max.poll.interval.ms` without retrieving any new records. The pollable source uses a `spring-integration-kafka` `KafkaMessageSource` underneath and pausing it causes it to pause **all of its assigned partitions**.